# Proof of Shelah's Theorem about inaccessible cardinals using Raisonnier Filters

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I'm studying Chapter 9, titled *The Raisonnier Filter* in Ralf Schindler's textbook *(Set Theory: Exploring Independence and Truth, 2014).*

The goal of this chapter is to prove Shelah's theorem: Assume every Σ13 set of reals is Lebesgue measurable. Then $\omega^V$ is inaccessible to the reals.

The argumentation goes in the following way:
We assume $ℵ_1$ is not inaccessible to the reals and all $Σ_{12}$ sets are Lebesgue measurable. Then one shows that there is a rapid filter F which is $Σ_{13}$. One finishes by proving that rapid filters are not Lebesgue measurable.

I have a technical question to one of the claims:
Let $a\in {}^\omega \omega$ such that $\omega_1^V = \omega_1^{L[a]}$.

Let $f: \omega \rightarrow \omega$ be monotone.

Define A:= $\{(x,y) \in ({}^\omega \omega)^2 \cap L[a,f]: x < _{L[a,f]} y\}$.

Claim: For each $y\in {}^\omega \omega \cap L[a,f] $, $\{x: (x,y)\in A \}$ is countable.

I don't understand why this set is countable.
Can anyone explain this to me?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Since $a$ computes $\omega_1$ correctly, $<_{L[a,f]}$ gives us an order of type $\omega_1$, so every proper initial segment is countable.